# IOS. Navigation Controller. Reuse ViewControllers

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

Here is my problem.
I have a view based application. 
I added a `NavigationController` to the `AppDelegate` as follows.

```
UINavigationController *nvc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:_viewController];    
navigationController = [nvc retain];
[nvc retain];     
[self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];
```

This code I got from internet. I don't know if it is correct.

In all the viewControllers I am doing the following to push a new view.

```
UIViewController *newViewController = [[NewViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:newViewController animated:TRUE];
```

1. I don't know why `self.navigationController` does not return nil in the pushed views. Is it using AppDelegate navigation controller somehow?
2. If I want to reuse some view controllers. I mean not alloc init every time that I want to call the view controller. How can I do that? Store a reference in the `AppDelegate`? Any other solution?
3. I have a complicated navigation. i.e. A, B, C are view controllers. A calls B. B calls C. C calls A. If I keep calling I am creating a new view controller each time. How can I reuse those view controllers (or pop and release the view from the stack when calling a new one)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) `navigationController` is a property of `UIViewController`. If the view controller is part of a navigation controller hierarchy then it will be set.

2) You'll have to manage this yourself. Storing a reference in the object that pushes that view controller would be the usual way to achieve this. So if A pushes B then A stores a reference to B, etc.

3) There's no way to get `UINavigationController` to do this for you. From what you're trying to do I assume you're coming from an Android background? Android has specific ways to do just that, but in iOS you'd have to code it yourself. You could do this by looking at `UINavigationControllerDelegate` and its `navigationController:didShowViewController:animated:` method. You could see when a view controller is pushed and if it's already in the stack then update the navigation stack (i.e. the `viewControllers` property of `UINavigationController`) to remove it from where it was. But that might get quite confusing for the user.

Comment: Maybe the answer is not using NavigationController. Is there a way to push a new view controller without using it? 
Maybe just pushing a new view controller, without adding it to any stack solves my problem. What do you think?

Comment: It totally depends on how you want the user to interact with your app. You can show a new view controller also by using `presentModalViewController:animated:` which will make the new view controller modal over the top of your current UI.

Comment: Matt,
Imagine that I have viewcontroller A, B and C.
A is the base one. A can go to B. B can go to C and C can go to B. B or C can return to A. Like this: A->B, B<->C, C->A, B->A.
Can I have a navigation controller in A, Push B, When B calls C push C and at the same time pop B in the A's navigation controller?

So I have the following:
- A calls B . Navigation Controller stack: A, B
- B calls C . Navigation Controller stack: A, C
- C calls B . Navigation Controller stack: A, B
- B returns to A. Navigation controller stack: A

Is that correct? How can I pop a view after calling another?

Comment: You could do that yes, by fiddling the `viewControllers` property on the navigation controller. Take the array that's there, remove the one you want to remove then add the new one. Then set it again. It's very unintuitive doing it like that though. iOS users assume that pressing the back button will go back to where they were rather than where they were 2 screens ago.